# ERROR:RELAXNGV:RELAXNG_ERR_EXTRACONTENT: Element form has extra content: sheet

Tags: python, xml, module, odoo

I'm going to developer work offer module.in that module if we selected the relevant division we can select workers  for work offer for them (in plantation industry). tried with comparing lunch module (lunch order form)
but i got this error. (OpenERP ver 7)

here is my view.xml

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="bpl_work_offer_form">
        <field name="name">bpl.work.offer.form</field>
        <field name="model">bpl.work.offer</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string='bpl_work_offer'>
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                        <group>
                            <field name='user_id' />
                        </group>
                        <group>
                            <field name='date_of_offer' />
                        </group>
                    </group>
                    <div name="Worker Selection"></div>
                    <separator string='Select workers' />
                    <field name='selected_workers_line_ids' nolabel='1'>
                        <tree string='List' editable='bottom'>
                            <field name='worker_id' />
                            <field name='is_selected' />
                        </tree>
                    </field>
                    <group class='oe_subtotal_footer oe_right'>
                        <field name='total_workers' />
                    </group>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

here is my model class

```
class bpl_work_offer(osv.osv):
    _name = "bpl.work.offer"
    _description = "BPL Work Offer"
    _columns = {
        'user_id': fields.many2one('res.users', 'User Name'),
        'date_of_offer': fields.date('Date'),
        'bpl_company_id':fields.many2one('bpl.company.registration', 'Company', help='Company'),
        'bpl_estate_id':fields.many2one('bpl.estate.registration', 'Estate', help='Estate'),
        'bpl_division_id':fields.many2one('bpl.division.registration', 'Division', help='Division'),
        'payment_type': fields.selection([('normal_work', 'Normal Work'), ('cash_work', 'Cash Work'), ('contract_work', 'Contract Work')], 'Payment Type'),
        'select_by': fields.selection([('by_name', 'By Names'), ('by_count', 'By Count')], 'Select  By'),
        'work_type': fields.selection([('tea', 'Tea'), ('rubber', 'Rubber'), ('sundry', 'Sundry')], 'Work Type'),
        'total_workers': fields.integer('Total Workers'),
        'selected_workers_line_ids': fields.one2many('selected.workers.line', 'worker_id', 'Workers', ondelete="cascade"),
    }

bpl_work_offer()

class selected_workers_line_ids(osv.osv):
    _name = 'selected.workers.line'
    _description = 'lunch order line'
    _columns = {
        'worker_id':fields.many2one('bpl.worker', 'Worker', help='Worker'),
        'is_selected': fields.boolean('Select', help="Selected or not"),
        }

selected_workers_line_ids()
```

my error is like this

```
2013-03-21 06:31:50,137 7539 ERROR bpl openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_ui_view: <string>:2:0:ERROR:RELAXNGV:RELAXNG_ERR_EXTRACONTENT: Element form has extra content: sheet
2013-03-21 06:31:50,164 7539 ERROR bpl openerp.tools.convert: Parse error in /home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/addons/bpl/bpl_view.xml:276: 
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="bpl_work_offer_form">
            <field name="name">bpl.work.offer.form</field>
            <field name="model">bpl.work.offer</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="bpl_work_offer">
........
  File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 1544, in _validate
    raise except_orm('ValidateError', '\n'.join(error_msgs))
except_orm: ('ValidateError', u'Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!')
2013-03-21 06:31:50,185 7539 INFO bpl werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2013 06:31:50] "POST /web/session/authenticate HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

ERROR occur when going to save.please check where is the issue with my mapping with tables

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/sql_db.py", line 226, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
IntegrityError: insert or update on table "selected_workers_line" violates foreign key constraint "selected_workers_line_worker_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (worker_id)=(1) is not present in table "bpl_worker".

2013-03-21 07:17:25,125 8275 ERROR bpl openerp.netsvc: Integrity Error
The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should right like this:

```
<form string='bpl_work_offer' version="7.0">
```

Then it works

Comment: error occured when i'm going to save that record.please help me to sorted it out

added to my post

Comment: your error show that some required fields you not give value : mandatory field is not correctly set please give required value

Comment: i double checked those .
seems issue with mapping in my model class.
can u guess wr z the issue.?

Comment: seeing your error it look like you have used worker_id but now this work_id is not present in your db

Comment: what is the reason to "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_BaseModel__view_look_dom_arch"'error.?

Comment: it means for which object you make view its not present in your data base

Comment: 'selected_workers_line_ids': fields.one2many('selected.workers.line', 'worker_id', 'Workers', ondelete="cascade"),
###
'worker_id':fields.many2one('bpl.worker', 'Worker', help='Worker'),

both are exist

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26617/discussion-between-priyan-changd-and-user1576199)